# Why do I get "table not found" even though I can see it created?

Tags: python, sql, django

I first created the User model before I read the Django documentation about authentication so I put all attributes in the same model. So, later I tried to split it into User and User profile. But when I run the the population script, it says User profile table is not found even though I saw the SQL that created it.

These are two classes connected to the User model that I import.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User)
        profilepic = models.ImageField(blank=True)
        city = models.ForeignKey(City)
        slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            @property
            def avg_rating(self):
                return self.userrating_set.all().aggregate(Avg('rating'))['rating__avg']

    class UserRating(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(User)
        comment = models.CharField(max_length=500)
        for_username = models.CharField(max_length=128)
        rating = models.IntegerField(default=5)

        def __unicode__(self):
            return unicode(self.rating)
```

And this is the portion of the population script where the problem is:

```
new_user = User.objects.get_or_create(username=username, email=email)[0]
#new_user.profilepic = profile_picture
new_user.firstname = first_name
new_user.secondname = last_name
new_user.save()

new_user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=new_user, city=created_city)
new_user_profile.slug = username
new_user_profile.save()
```

And this is the error I get when running the script:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bnbih\app_name\populationScript.py", line 108, in <module>
    populate()
  File "C:\Users\bnbih\app_name\populationScript.py", line 101, in populate
    new_user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create()
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 92, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 422, in get_or_create
    return self.get(**lookup), False
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 351, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 122, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 966, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 265, in iterator
    for row in compiler.results_iter():
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 700, in results_iter
    for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 786, in execute_sql
    [Finished in 0.8s with exit code 1]cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 81, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 485, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: mainapp_userprofile
```

Comment: Where did you see the "SQL create it"? If you run `makemigrations`/`migrate`, does anything show up?

Comment: When I run the SQLmigrate I can see: CREATE TABLE "mainapp_userprofile"

Answer (score 1):

Django's [`sqlmigrate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/django-admin/#sqlmigrate) just shows you *what* will get run, it doesn't apply any changes, you need to run [`migrate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/django-admin/#migrate)

> Prints the SQL for the named migration. This requires an active database connection, which it will use to resolve constraint names; this means you must generate the SQL against a copy of the database you wish to later apply it on.

Comment: @Sei.M. - Why have you deleted the migrations? Its *never* a good idea to just delete them, You may need to run `migrate mainapp XXXX` where `XXXX` is the prefix number of the latest migration, (maybe `migrate mainapp 0` first or just deleting your local database and remaking it)